# Return the index and array after reduced

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am playing with reduce method provided by mozilla.  Underscore provides its own version which seems very similar.  Reducing an array is very simple.

```
ArrayName.reduce(function(a,b) {
  return a +b;
});
```

I use a very similar approach when sorting arrays as well.  However, what I do not understand is how to return a list of calls.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce  Provides a really cool table that shows how their method works.  I set my array pretty much the same

```
var array = [1,2,3,100,55,88,2];
var sortArray= function(a,b) {
  return a -b;
}
var sorted = array.sort(sortArray);


var reduced = sorted.reduce(function(previousValue,currentValue, index,array){
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

What I wanted to set up though was each call that was made.  I figured that I could simply reference the index in the return value with a , at the end.

```
return previousValue + currentValue, index;
```

However, that only returns the index.   I am trying to figure a way to get the value of each call.   Does this approach allow you to get each call?

Comment: The array after `reduce` become a single variable, I don't know what you mean the index and array  after `reduce`. Did you want to get an new array as `[1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+100, .....]` from your original one?

Comment: I got the total sum 251 which would be at an index of 6.  I am trying to figure out how to get each index.  Which is very similar to what you are asking.   1, 1+2, 1+2+3

Comment: *What I wanted to set up though was each call that was made.* I cannot understand this sentence, nor the phrase "get the value of each call". What is your desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `reduce` for what you are doing. Try

```
function running_total(array) {
    var sum = 0;
    return array.map(function(elt) {
      return sum += elt;
    };
}
```

Reduce is about "boiling down" an array to a "single thing". In contrast, map is about "transforming" elements of the array. Your problem (as I understand it) is to **transform** each element of the array into the sum of itself and all the preceding elements. Therefore, conceptually, it's a map, not a reduce.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `,` in the return statement will only return index due to the comma operator rule

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
  console.log(previousValue+"--"+currentValue)
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

this will do want you want

Answer (score 0):

You can create another array and store its value for each progress.

```js
var array = [1,2,3,100,55,88,2];
var sortArray= function(a,b) {
  return a -b;
}
var sorted = array.sort(sortArray);

var progress = [];
var reduced = sorted.reduce(function(previousValue,currentValue, index,array){
  progress[index] = previousValue + currentValue;
  return progress[index];
}, 0);
// ^^^^^ 
// give it a init value so it starts at first element.

console.log(progress);
```

However, as [torazaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31749055/1737627) says, as you expect to get an array, you should use `.map`  which returns an `array` instead of `.reduce`.

Comment: @torazaburo I'm really sorry that I make an wrongly reference, thanks for the correction. Upvoted your answer as it seems to be exactly what OP wanted.